# How to get access token in Outlook addin for iphone and android?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created an outlook add-in that works fine on outlook online and Outlook desktop app. But, on the Outlook app for iOS and Android this is not working as iphone and android does not support IdentityAPI 1.3.

Do we have any timeline when this will be supported in phones and also can anyone help me to get backlog list of outlook addin development?

Comment: Identity API 1.3 is currently not supported on Android & iOS Outlook clients. We have taken your request and please follow Outlook mobile add-ins public documentation for more updates.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-mobile-addins